# USB-Bluetooth not working on Fedora 15. Already tried systemctl start

Tags: bluetooth, fedora-15

I'm having a problem with my usb bluetooth, in Fedora 14 was just working but now it does not. I know theres is a bug that you have to fix in Fedora 15 with gnome-shell using:

```
# systemctl status bluetooth.service
# systemctl enable bluetooth.service
# systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

I already dit it following severals tutorials, but none of them helped. I tried:

```
# systemctl stop bluetooth.service
# systemctl load bluetooth.service
# systemctl enable bluetooth.service
# systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

But it didn't help as I was expecting. Ideas?

The main tutorial I followed was: [Tutorial](http://www.sohailriaz.com/how-to-fix-bluetooth-in-fedora-15/)

Answer (score 1):

They key is to restart. Try:

```
systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```